# phpMyAdmin datetimepicker for php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, phpmyadmin, datetimepicker

I'd like the user to book their appointment through the form. This is the codes for my database.php I was able to successfully make the codes work. However i have a problem in my database.

```
$conn = dbConnect();

   if (! $conn)

   die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");

       $sql = "INSERT INTO Appointment (Client_ID,Svc_ID,Appt_DateTime) 
       VALUES ('$_POST[ClientID]','$_POST[ApptType]','$_POST[DateTime]')";


    mysql_query($sql,$conn);

    dbDisconnect($conn);
```

This is the codes I used and tried to enter but my database shows a result of "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

I want to show my client a datetime format as this (shown below) in the field

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
       jQuery('#DateTime').datetimepicker({
        format:'D, d M Y H:i',

     });
   });
 </script>
```

however how do i format it in a way to allow the database to read it as "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" and store the appointment date and time for my datetime datatype?

Comment: use function for convert date

Comment: The value of ``$_POST[DateTime]`` would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default datetime format in mysql is `Y-m-d H:i:s`.So it is saving `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as it is not getting the proper format.convert it first then save. Try with -

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Appointment (Client_ID,Svc_ID,Appt_DateTime) 
   VALUES ('$_POST[ClientID]','$_POST[ApptType]','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['DateTime']))."')";
```

Comment: Happy to help you..And plz accept the answer if it solves the problem. :)